# " === " in Kotlin. What does it mean?

Tags: kotlin

```
companion object DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<MarsProperty>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: MarsProperty, newItem: MarsProperty): Boolean {
            return oldItem === newItem
        }
```

What does `===` mean?

Answer (score 1):

The `===` operator in Kotlin is the referential equality operator. Meaning: Do these references point to the same place in memory (are they physically the same object).

As opposed to `==`, which is the structural equality operator. Meaning: Do these objects have the same structure (are they logically the same object).

Note that two objects will be structurally equal (same makeup) if they are referentially equal (point to the same place in memory).

Answer (score 1):

as the documentation says:

> In Kotlin there are two types of equality:
> --Structural equality (a check for equals()).
> --Referential equality (two
> references point to the same object);

the referential equality operator `===` as the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html#referential-equality) says checks if both variables point to the same object in the memory.

> Referential equality is checked by the === operation (and its negated
> counterpart !==). a === b evaluates to true if and only if a and b
> point to the same object. For values which are represented as
> primitive types at runtime (for example, Int), the === equality check
> is equivalent to the == check.

on the other hand the structural equality checks for `equals()` method of the class.

so for example consider the following code:

```
val one = Integer(1)
val anotherOne = Integer(1)

println(one == anotherOne)       //true
println(one === anotherOne)      //false
```

the structural equality operator `==` returns true because Integer has a equals method inside which checks for their actual values, but the referential equality operator `===` return false because their references are different.

consider another example:

```
class Person(val name: String)
val donald = Person(“donald”)
val anotherDonald = Person(“donald”)

println(donald == anotherDonald)      //false
println(donald === anotherDonald)     //false
```

in this case, both operators return false because the class `Person` doesn't have a equals method and doesn't check for its actual value. but if you override the equals method or make `Person` a data class, then the first one returns true because the data class automatically overrides the equals method. but `===` still returns false because the references are different.